# SQL group by different levels on the same dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, hadoop, hive, cloudera

I have the following dataset, and I hope to create different groups to count the occurrence of values under name.

Have: (county is in string)

```
name   state  county 
apple   MD      1
apple   DC      1
pear    VA      1
pear    VA      2
pear    CA      5
peach   CO      3
peach   CO      3
peach   CO      2
peach   CO      2
```

Want:

```
name   state  county freq_name  freq_state  freq_county
apple   MD      1     2            1            2
apple   DC      1     2            1            2
pear    VA      1     3            2            3
pear    VA      2     3            2            3
pear    CA      5     3            1            3
peach   CO      3     4            4            2
peach   CO      2     4            4            2
```

I believe by SQL , over partition will allow count by different levels
something like:

```
count(name) over (partition by name) as freq_name,
count(name) over (partition by state) as freq_state,
count(name) as freq_county
from have
group by name,state, county;
```

For some reason, this piece of code does not give me the right counts for freq_name. I also want to check if my code for freq_state and freq_county are accurate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select name, state, county, count(*) as this_count,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by name) as freq_name,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by state) as freq_state,
       sum(count(*)) as freq_county
from have
group by name, state, county;
```

Comment: Will count(*) allow me to count the appearance of name by state only?

Comment: @lydias . .. This is using a window function.  And "yes".  Did you run the query?

Answer (score 1):

For the `freq_name`, use `count(*)` instead of `count(name)`

```
count(*) over (partition by name) as freq_name,
count(name) over (partition by state) as freq_state,
count(name) as freq_county
from have
group by name,state, county;
```

Comment: Also, does my code for freq_state look right? I'm working with large dataset, it is difficult to validate on detailed levels.I'm pretty sure freq_county should work...